# item label positioning problem

Tags: tabularx, enumitem

Without the `minipage`, I get the item where I'd like it to be, but the label (foo) vertically centered whereas I'd like it vertically aligned with the first line. And with `\\`, the item's position is changed, and the label too high. How can I get it right?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\ProvideDocumentEnvironment
{sbs}
{+b}
{\begin{tabular*}
   {\textwidth}{
   @{}
   p{.45\textwidth}
   @{\extracolsep{1em}}
   p{.45\textwidth}
   @{}}#1}
   {\end{tabular*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  [nosep,
  align=right,
  labelindent=-1pt,
  labelsep=1pt%,
%  topsep=0pt,
%  parsep=0pt,
%  partopsep=0pt,
%  itemsep=0pt
  ]
\item[foo]%\begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}\end{minipage}\\
  \begin{sbs}
    \lipsum[1][1] & \lipsum[1][2]\\
    \lipsum[1][3] & \lipsum[1][4]
  \end{sbs}
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why you insert empty `minipage` after  `\item[foo]`?  What it it purpose? `\\ ` after some text start new line in it, so it is expected that in your case you have empty line after `\item[foo]` when you terminate empty `minipage` by `\\ `.

Comment: There is `minipage` so as to be able to do `slash slash` after it, iow `\newline`. The comment out symbol `%` should really be before `\begin{minipage}`, I'm correcting accordinly.

Comment: Why you like to terminate `\itrm[foo]` with `\\ `?  You cant have both at the same time: require new line and have new line aligned with line (with `\item[foo]`) before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To long to be a comment ...

It is not clear what you like to achieve in your `description`. If you like that first line of text in the environment `sbs` is aligned with item label, than a possible simple solution is:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\ProvideDocumentEnvironment{sbs}{+b}
{\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}[t]    % see added [t]
        {@{} p{.45\textwidth} @{\extracolsep{1em}} p{.45\textwidth} @{}}
   #1
}
{\end{tabular*}
}
 
\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  [nosep,
  align=right,
  labelindent=-1pt,
  labelsep=1pt%,
  ]
\item[foo]
  \begin{sbs}
    \lipsum[1][1] & \lipsum[1][2]\\
    \lipsum[1][3] & \lipsum[1][4]
  \end{sbs}
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]